# Leaflet L.Icon marker not removing on Map reload

Tags: leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

Map contains two types of markers
Circle icon is added by:

```
      let circle = new customCircleMarker([item.latitude, item.longitude], {
        color: '#2196F3',
        fillColor: '#2196F3',
        fillOpacity: 0.8,
        radius: radM,
        addressId: item.address_id
      }).bindTooltip(`Address: <b>${item.address}</b><br/>
                   Patients from this address: <b>${item.total_patients}</b><br/>
                   Production: <b>$${item.total_production}</b><br/>`)
        .addTo(this.mapInstance).on('click', this.circleClick);
```

Icon marker is added in the following method:

// create marker object, pass custom icon as option, pass content and options to popup, add to map

```
      // create marker object, pass custom icon as option, pass content and options to popup, add to map
      L.marker([item.latitude, item.longitude], { icon: chartIcon })
        .bindTooltip(`Address: <b>${item.address}</b><br/>
                   Patients from this address: <b>${item.total_patients}</b><br/>
                   Production: <b>$${item.total_production}</b><br/>`)
        .addTo(this.mapInstance).on('click', this.circleClick);
```

On clearing map Icon marker is not removed

Map clearing function:

```
if (this.mapInstance) {
  for (let i in this.mapInstance._layers) {
    if (this.mapInstance._layers[i]._path !== undefined) {
      try {
        this.mapInstance.removeLayer(this.mapInstance._layers[i]);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log('problem with ' + e + this.mapInstance._layers[i]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're checking for a `_path` property before removing. It will skip the `L.Marker` layers because they don't have a `_path` property, only vector layers (extended from L.Path) do.

If you ever need to delete only certain layer types from your map you are best off by grouping them in a grouping layer like `L.LayerGroup` or `L.FeatureGroup` and then using their `clearLayers` method:

```
var layerGroup = new L.LayerGroup([
    new L.Marker(...),
    new L.CircleMarker()
]).addTo(map);

layerGroup.clearLayers();
```

If that is not an option you could iterate the map's layers and then check the instance of the layer:

```
function customClearLayers () {
    map.eachLayer(function (layer) {
        if (layer instanceof L.Marker || layer instanceof L.CircleMarker) {
            map.removeLayer(layer);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. Got it fixed (y) @iH8